# Viewing file in Chinese as UTF-8 encoded on Solaris without changing the locale to Chinese

Tags: encoding, utf-8

**Use Case:**
I have a client server setup where server is a Solaris machine and client can be any windows, linux, etc. Client while coming up needs to create a resource bundle object based on client's locale which in turn fetches a Chinese property file maintained at the server (for some design reasons).

**Requirement:**
I need to maintain the Chinese file at server (utf-8 encoded) without changing server's locale to Chinese. (Similarly, may be later, we may introduce support for some other language. So practically we can't keep server to point to multiple locale simultaneously. Hope I made my point here!)

**Problem:**
I create Chinese property file on windows machine and then FTP it to Solaris machine and try to view it using VI editor. It gets encoded to some default solaris encoding as shown below:

*\217\251\300disk-redundancy.mirrors.label=\207\376\251\207\251\226\207\242\346\206\304\272\205\326\277\207\326\251\205\273\362
LoginWindow.login_label=\207\326\251\205\273\362 Id:*

**P.S.** Changing the locale on the server can't be the part of the solution as already explained above.

**FYI:**

```
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_ALL=
```

**Note:** 
1. cat is showing different result when compared to what described above in VI. Please find below output of cat:

▒▒▒disk-redundancy.mirrors.label=▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ĺ▒ֿ▒֩▒▒▒ LoginWindow.login_label=▒֩▒▒▒ Id:

I tried to programmatically access file without opening it any editor which, I presume, indicates that the problem is not with the editor.

*java DebugTool ?? Id:*

2. Also encoding finder tool on solaris returns UTF-8.

*auto_ef -a chinese.properties*

*UTF-8 1.00*

3. I tried to download this file back to windows and view it in an editor and could successfully view it as Chinese file.

*disk-redundancy.mirrors.label=系统监控器登录*

*disk-redundancy.mirrors.value=登录 Id:*

Comment: Sounds like it's mostly a vi related problem!? Have the actual contents of the file changed, or is vi simply unable to display/interpret it?

Comment: cat <filename> is showing different result when compared to what described above in VI. Please find below output of cat:

▒▒▒disk-redundancy.mirrors.label=▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ĺ▒ֿ▒֩▒▒▒
LoginWindow.login_label=▒֩▒▒▒ Id:

To answer to your question, I have followed steps below:
1. I uploaded the file on the server.
2. Needed to change the permission and ownership to 444 and root, respectively.
3. Tried to print the value of a key defined in the properties file using resource bundle object i.e., didn't open the file using any editor.

java DebugTool
?? Id:

Comment: What I meant in the above statement was that I tried to programmatically access file without opening it any editor which, I presume, indicates that the problem is not with the editor.